# map operator [] operands

Tags: c++, dictionary, operands

Hi all I have the following in a member function

```
int tt = 6; 
vector<set<int>>& temp = m_egressCandidatesByDestAndOtMode[tt]; 
set<int>& egressCandidateStops = temp.at(dest);
```

and the following declaration of a member variable

```
map<int, vector<set<int>>> m_egressCandidatesByDestAndOtMode;
```

However I get an error when compiling (Intel Compiler 11.0)

```
1>C:\projects\svn\bdk\Source\ZenithAssignment\src\Iteration\PtBranchAndBoundIterationOriginRunner.cpp(85): error: no operator "[]" matches these operands
1>            operand types are: const std::map<int, std::vector<std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>>>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>>>>>> [ const int ]
1>          vector<set<int>>& temp = m_egressCandidatesByDestAndOtMode[tt]; 
1>                                                                    ^
```

I know it's got to be something silly but I can't see what I've done wrong.

**UPDATE** I'm calling this from a const member function which is why the member variable's type is const so I thought that something like the following should fix it:

```
int dest = 0, tt = 6; 
const set<int>& egressCandidateStops = m_egressCandidatesByDestAndOtMode[tt].at(dest);
```

But no dice... still the same error.

Comment: The answer from Potatoswatter is correct. To avoid your problem, you need to use find.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> operand types are: **const std::map**< int …

`map::operator[]` does not work with a `const map`.

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752549/why-cant-i-pass-const-map-structure-to-a-function-in-c/2752556#2752556) this a few days ago.

> map::operator[] is a little odd. It
>   does this:
>
> 1. Look for the key.
> 2. If found, return it.
> 3. If not, insert it and default-construct its associated
>      value.
> 4. Then return a reference to the new value.
>
> Step 3 is incompatible with constness.
>   Rather than have two
>   differently-functioning operator[]
>   overloads, the language forces you to
>   use map::find for const objects.

Comment: Thats exactly it!! I will mark as answered in seven minutes, don't know why I can't already... if the answer is right it's right :)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning `std::map::at` now.

Answer (score 7):

The prototype for `[]` is

```
 data_type& operator[](const key_type& k)
```

i.e. a non const operation, so you can't call it on a member from a const member function .

You could change the code to:

```
std::map<...>::const_iterator where = m_egressCandidatesByDestAndOtMode.find(tt);
if (egressCandidatesByDestAndOtMode.end() != where) {
    const vector<set<int>>& temp = where->second;
}
```